# Regex to remove white spaces at the begining and ending of html tag content

Tags: regex

I need a regex as in topic. E.g.

```
<span>     Hello world!   </span>
```

goes to

```
<span>Hello world!</span>
```

In general we can say:

```
<tag>    
        [some content]
                           </tag>
```

goes to

```
<tag>[some content]</tag>
```

Comment: Something like: `Give me the code, please!`

Comment: seeing as how HTML naturally shortens multiple code whitespace to a single (at most) whitespace on browser output, this question seems entirely unneeded

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of a trim method on the content of the tags or use a regex like you asked:

```
((?<=>)\s+|\s+(?=<))
```

See this [working sample on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PEMFzr/1)

### Explanation

This expression matches one or more (`+`) whitespaces (`\s`) that are either

1. `(?<=>)\s+` following a closing tag (`>`) **or** (`|`)
2. `\s+(?=<)` follwed by a opening tag (`<`)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `trim` to remove spaces.

Comment: I'm unaware that HTML or regex has a `trim` function.